# HubSection Header tap event?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

How to get Tap event on Hub section Header?

```
 <HubSection.HeaderTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <TextBlock Text="" Foreground="#009CDE" Width="250"/>
       <Image x:Name="SendToSap" Source="image/Sync_To_SAP.png" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="5,0,50,0" Tapped="SendToSap_Tapped"></Image>
    </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
  </HubSection.HeaderTemplate>

 private void SendToSap_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   }
```

How to get this on image tap event?

Answer (score 1):

Is it not working as is? Maybe you need to set `IsTapEnabled="True"`

If you need to add more code behind in your `DataTemplate` - usually you can move all the contents of the template into a `UserControl` and handle the events there.